# Sliders episode that ends with a kid flying

Tags: episode-identification, sliders

In the end of this episode, after solving the crisis of the week on one world and moving on to another, the main characters freak out when they see a woman dangling her daughter from the upper floor of a two-story house. The mother lets go, and her child sprouts wings from her back and flies to safety. After this happens the mom says something to the effect of "It's the only way they learn," to the sliders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is 3x09, [*The Prince of Slides*](https://earthprime.com/episode-guide/the-prince-of-slides/). The girl flying at the end was a fun 'throwaway' world.

> **Girl:** *Please! Please! Don't! Don't! Don't do it, please!*
>
> [The mother throws her off the balcony and she sprouts wings]
>
> **Girl:** *Look, Mommy, no feet!*
>
> **Mom:** *[Oh, it's the only way they learn.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGyK6ZR2L0s)*
>
> [image]